# Javascript: How to pass an array with specific index to a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let say I have an array:-

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

I need to pass only "1" and "4" to function below

```
function func1(onlyArray){
     //Do Stuff...
}
```

I have tried both but both also dont work

```
func1(arr[1,4])
func1(arr[[1],[4]])
```

Can anyone show me the right way or give me some keyword?

Comment: `func(arr[1], arr[4])`

Comment: @wostex but the function only accept one parameter, will this detect as two parameter?

Comment: @vbnewbie, use this: `func([arr[1], arr[4]])`

Comment: What is the type of the parameter?

Comment: Do you have control over the function or are you locked into it only accepting a single argument? If you can't change the function, how will the function know how many parameters it's receiving?

Comment: thx everyone understand already...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this: 
`func([arr[1], arr[4]])`

We are taking the elements at index `1` and `4` of the array `arr` and creating a new array with those elements. Then we pass that newly created array to `func`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a single array instead of 2, use this:

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];

function func1(onlyArray){
     //Do Stuff...
    console.log(onlyArray); // [1, 4]
}

func1(arr.filter((item,index) => index === 1 || index === 4));
```

Comment: `[arr[1], arr[4]]` is much simpler, why not just use that ?

Comment: @Taurus, he just provided another solution.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Oh

Comment: @Taurus, I've included an optional way to get a single array. Yours works as well.

Comment: I think this better fits the op's question. Since you want to pass a single array consisting only of 1 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

So using your array:

`var arr = [0,1,2,3,4];`

and your function:

`function myFunction(newArr){
  //Do stuff
  console.log(newArr);
};`

You can wrap the array indexes you want to use inside of their own array when you call the function, like the following:

`myFunction([arr[1], arr[4]]); //Output is [1, 4]`

Comment: How is this different than @Taurus's answer?

Comment: It isn't. Their answer is more brief and earlier than my comment. This is my first time trying to help on StackOverflow, so I spent more time learning how to use the markup than I really did responding. Sorry, my friend.

Comment: No problem - thanks for the explanation, and your willingness to help!